# How to fire like and range query on PII encrypted column in mysql

Tags: encryption, amazon-kms, pii

I have different encrypted columns in my MySQL table for different PII data like email, date of birth, etc.I am using AES envelope encryption coupled with AWS KMS. The encryption and decryption is handled in the application. No MySQL inbuilt encryption functionalities are used.                       I am able to perform the full-text match of input email by encrypting it but unable to perform like query operation. Please suggest me solutions for performing different MySQL operations on encrypted PII data.

Comment: How are the columns encrypted? Enterprise TDE? Explicitly using functions like `AES_ENCRYPT()`? There is not enough information here to answer.

Comment: I am using AES envelope encryption coupled with AWS KMS. The encryption and decryption is handled in the application. No MySQL inbuilt encryption functionalities are used